# Show that Bellman-Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, integral-inequality

I'm trying to prove the theorem general of the **Bellman-Gronwall's inequality**:

> Assume that $u(t)$ be real valued non - negative continuous function, and such that $$u(t)\le u(\tau )+\int_{\tau}^{t}f(t_1)u(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1, \forall a< \tau <t <b$$ where $f(t)\in C(a,b), f(t)\ge 0$
>
> Then $$u(t_0)\exp \left ( -\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ) \le u(t) \le u(t_0)\exp \left ( \int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ), \forall a<t_0 \le t<b$$

- 1/ I'll show that  $\bf u(t) \le u(t_0)\exp \left ( \int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ) \tag 1$

We use $G-B$:

> Let $u(t)$ and $f(t)$ be non - negative continuous functions
>   on $\Bbb R^+$ for which the inequality
>   $$u(t) \le C+ \int_{t_0}^{t}u(s)f(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
>   holds, where $C$ is a non - negative constant.
>
> Then $$u(t) \le C \cdot \exp \left ( \int_{t_0}^{t}f(s)\mathrm{d}s \right )$$

where $C=u(t_0)$ and $\tau=t_0$. It's obvious. And we're done.

- 2/ I'll show that $$u(t_0)\exp \left ( -\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ) \le u(t)  \tag 2$$

But I have stuck when I try to show that $(2)$. Can anyone have a solution?

Any help is always appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The left inequality is wrong. Take $f=0$.

Comment: If you take $f=0$ then $u(t_0) \le u(t) \le u(t_0)$ . Hence, $u(t)=u(t_0)$. And you are incorrect. :(

Comment: Does $u(t) = u(t_0)$ not contradict your assumption, if $u$ is a strictly decreasing function, which also satisfy the first inequality condition?

Comment: First, your tone is bit rude while it is you who is seeking help from others. Second, you don't even point out it was Theorem 8 you are referring when asking others to look up a reference. Third, can you not think about whether a statement makes sense or explain why you think it does? Regarding the specific problem, a strictly decreasing function $u$ satisfies the first condition for some $a$, namely $a=0$. Obviously, the first inequality in the conclusion is not satisfied. Either this "theorem" is wrong or there is a missing condition. If you think I am wrong, tell me where.

Comment: Books may have typos too. Books are not bible. Reasoning is not a religion.

Comment: I read some books but these are all the same I quoted above. It's reason because I wrote "I don't have much time to explain". I'm sorry if you think I was rude. Anyway, if you have a solution, or If you have an example when you think it's not true, and I'll read your post carefully . sincere!

Comment: apology accepted. I have already given you a counterexample as before: for a strictly decreasing $u$ and $f=0$, the condition is satisfied but the first inequality in the conclusion is violated. Now can you check my statement and tell me if you agree, and tell me where exactly you do not agree, using your own faculty of mathematical reasoning, not appealing to unfounded authority? There are only two ways to resolve an argument in mathematics, prove it or coming up with a counterexample --- or show where either goes wrong.